# "Go to implementation" of an Android API class opens .class file, not .java

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an app in Android Studio 0.4.0 (but this issue happened also on earlier versions), and when I try to access the implementation of an Android-specific class using the IDE's shortcut "Go to implementation", it opens the .class file of that class, and not the .java.

In another computer and different project, I'm sure that shortcut opens the java file, which is desired because I can see the actual implementation code, comments, and javadoc.

For instance, I have this class:

```
package com.example;
...
import android.app.Fragment;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
}
```

When I have the caret on `Fragment` and do "Go to implementation", it opens `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-19/android.jar!/android/app/Fragment.class`. The expected behaviour should be to open `$ANDROID_SDK/sources/android-19/android/app/Fragment.java` (or where ever else lies the correct Fragment.java file).

In the SDK manager, I'm sure I downloaded the sources for Android SDK, API 19 and API 17. My Manifest file states:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    />
```

Changing the target SDK to 19 has no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is no longer a problem as of Android Studio 2.0. The Android gradle plugin will automatically attach the support libraries' source and javadocs to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching source jars or directories to included libraries isn't supported yet in Gradle-based Android Studio projects. The closest bug you can use to track progress is:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59220