# Android Studio does not show documentation of Support Library

Tags: android-studio, android-support-library

When I type ctrl-q in Android Studio, the documentation opens, works fine. But if I have API calls from the support library (like ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs), I see a more or less empty window.

But it workes some updates ago?! IIRC?!

The code compiles and works, I did not change anything but installing Android and Studio updates...  Now it's Android Studio 0.9.2, Support Libraray 21.0.1

In build.gradle I have com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+, and "0.1" not working, only "0.0" or "0.+". Kind of library version mismatch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the documentation for the support libraries inside Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490297/how-to-display-the-documentation-for-the-support-libraries-inside-android-studio)