# How view support library documentation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

By pressing Shift + F1 on some method in code editor I can open standard API documentation in browser. 
But, how open support library documentation in android studio 1.02 (by pressing Shift + F1 ) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the documentation for the support libraries inside Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490297/how-to-display-the-documentation-for-the-support-libraries-inside-android-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio go to Preferences > Editor > General > Other, find "Show quick doc on mouse over Delay (ms)" (it's at the bottom) checkbox and check it.

Now when you hover your mouse over any method a popup with doc will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with *CTRL+Q* (or *F1* on Mac) shortcut?

[Android Studio Tips and Tricks](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html#key-commands)